# Cannot drop schema because it is being reference by object

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I've looked through dozens of posts regarding this error and they all have the same solution, drop all the objects referenced by the schema - but the object the error gives me does not exist.

So I try to run the following syntax

```
DROP SCHEMA [Application]
```

And the error it gives is

```
Cannot drop schema 'Application' because it is being referenced by object 'ApplicationRequestTable'.
```

So I think "ok no problem, I'll remove that object, just like the past couple of views it pointed out", so I type

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = N'ApplicationRequestTable'
```

And nothing is returned from the above - am I doing something wrong because it looks like my schema is referencing an object that does not exit?!?  I further verify by typing

```
SELECT o.name, s.name FROM sys.objects o JOIN sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id ORDER by s.name
```

And there is not a single object under the Application schema...  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated as I cannot see anything at all referencing this schema now?

Version: SQL Server 2014 SP1 (build 12.0.4100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all objects are in sys.objects

At least...

- sequences (sys.sequences)
- user defined table types (sys,table_types)
- service broker objects (sys.service_queues)

Full list

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ac.object_id) FROM sys.all_columns ac WHERE name = 'schema_id'
```

Comment: I found the table in the table_types (it is a user defined table after all)

`SELECT * FROM sys.table_types WHERE name = N'ApplicationRequestTable'`

That ApplicationRequestTable DOES NOT appear in sys.all_columns though so you've got that bit wrong ... 
`SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ac.object_id) FROM sys.all_columns ac ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(ac.object_id)`
returns 14786 rows and ApplicationRequestTable is not one of them, the table Application.ApplicationRequestTable also doesn't exist in Object Explorer.

Comment: Explain why I'm wrong even though you've found your object in the schema you want to remove. Application.ApplicationRequestTable is not a table. It is a **table type**, It appears under Programmability..Types node (not Tables node) and won't have any entries in sys.columns. I mentioned sys.all_columns so you could find schema dependent objects: not look up metadata about your object.

Comment: Ah ok I see now.  Your wording says "Full list" so I therefore assumed my ApplicationRequestTable should be in a so-called "Full" list - you meant the list of object types (if that's correct wording, i.e. table_types)?  So selecting from one of those 24 in my list would return an answer for my ApplicationRequestTable

Comment: Full list above doesn't work for me. Trying to drop a schema, SQL refuses with that same message on the title. And the query you posted returns an empty result set....

Comment: @AlexandreM then you have another object that depends on the schema. Look at sys.objects, schema_id column to start. Or ask a new question